# Issues booting up old Intel 6U tower server

Tags: boot, server, raid, intel

I am completely new to servers... I was given an Intel 6U server tower from my boss...  I haven't found a ton of info on my particular issue anywhere online... I'm trying to install ubuntu server 20.4 to a raid 6 set up through the raid controller.

Server board S5520HC

Dual Intel Xeon E5630.
32gb of Ram.
4x 500Gb HDD as raid 6
Integrated RAID I/O Expansion Module AXXROMBSASMR so it's using integrated raid
It has a huge air vent that is covering most of the mobo. It's  a huge issue getting out :/

I have a few questions here...

I've tried multiple things all for them to fail

1. Install ubuntu to the virtual drive created when making the raid. Install finishes. Reboot equals blinking underscore black screen.
2. Install ubuntu on a completely separate HDD, (booted it to make sure it boots fine) and plugging the drive in as a external drive through a usb adapter. (shows up in the boot options) Equals blinking underscore black screen.
3. Leave all the drives out of a raid and create a software raid through installation. (I didn't... But I'm assuming you have to go in and remove the drives from the raid controller... Didn't because it's my first time messing with it .. didn't wanna take it apart of I didn't have to). Drives don't even show up in installation.

I know I'm probably just stupid on the subject of servers and how they work... I just can't find alot of info

Am I just completely missing a point that like, that kind of OS can't run on this thing?? Or?

Edit 12/16/2020:

Hooked up a complete separate HDD not connected to the raid controller. (Straight to the mobo) to install ubuntu to. New drive shows up in the boot menu after install results in exact same thing. Blinking underscore black screen.

Comment: Could you share some details about the hardware? 6U tells us its size, but nothing else. What sort of CPU? How much memory? Etc.. Specificity is important when solving problems.

Comment: My apologies. Still learning about the hardware

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you've added to your question, it sounds like you have a Dell PowerEdge R610.

There are a couple of things you'll need to do *before* installing Ubuntu, and it sounds like you did them initially, but these are the steps:

1. When booting, enter the RAID controller using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
2. Press <kbd>F2</kbd> and select "Create New VD" (Virtual Disk). RAID0 is the default, but you can also choose RAID1 and RAID10. RAID5 is not recommended as a boot device for Ubuntu.
3. Select which physical disks you will add to the raid. The <kbd>spacebar</kbd> toggles the selection.
4. Select "OK" once you have selected all of the disks you wish to add to the virtual disk

Next, the virtual disk will need to be initialised. Press <kbd>F2</kbd>, choose "Initialisation", and then "Fast Init". Choose "Yes" when asked to confirm the changes. This process may take a couple of minutes, but now your RAID is ready to go.

Next,

1. Insert the Ubuntu installation USB stick (or DVD)
2. Reboot the server
3. Press <kbd>F11</kbd> to bring up the boot menu

From here you'll see a list of options to boot from. Choose the device containing the Ubuntu installation media.

Now you can follow [the steps outlined by Canonical](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-server#4-choose-your-language):

1. Choose your language
2. Choose your keyboard layout
3. Choose the installation type
4. Configure networking
5. Configure storage
6. Select devices
7. Confirm partitions
8. Confirm changes
9. Set up a profile

Once done, remove the installation media and reboot the server.

Welcome to the world of server management

Comment: In the raid bios, there is an option to mark the VD as bootable? Should I make sure to do that or will the installation do that itself with grub

Comment: Mark it as bootable. Grub will handle the rest.

Comment: Followed step by step. Changed my RAID 6 a RAID 1. Reinstalled ubuntu. Completed installation. Rebooted 
Still no dice. Same result. Blinking underscore black screen

Comment: Have you confirmed the "Boot Sequence" in the BIOS? It may be pointing to a VD that no longer exists. If the system is running in UEFI mode, you'll need to hit [F11] near the start of the boot to access the UEFI boot manager and verify the correct settings are in place.

Comment: F11 isn't an option for me. I have F2 for Setup. F6 for boot menu. F12 for network boot. And Ctrl+G for raid. Searching through the manual for more info